# What has been said about innocent babies among people who recieved Allah's punishment?

Tags: punishment, baby

Many cities and nations have recieved Allah's punishment for their wrongdoings.

However, statistically speaking, a nation has newborn babies almost in any time.

What has been said about those babies? Because apparently newborns are innocent.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want a Quranic verse or a Hadith about innocents dying in a disaster? Or something else? Because, this is more like "Problem of Evil" type question, which can't be covered here as it is subjective & emotional.

Comment: Yeah I want Quranic references about them.

Answer (score 1):

Allah is the one who gives and takes life of everyone even today from old people to newborn babies.

The time of punishment isn't any more special. He takes the life of the newborn babies and gives them their fair reward in the hereafter.

Answer (score -1):

Well yes newborn are innocent but when Allah's punishment come every one has to deal with it. It(Allah's punishment) is just like a natural disaster that do not see gender, age or status just kill people.

Any way those children who died in the punishment will go to heaven not in hell.

Answer (score -2):

All children are innocent they all go to paradise without reckoning. In any circumstances, and at any age before puberty.